# Why doesn't dajax assign work?

Tags: django, assign, dajax

Either I'm not seeing the obvious or something fundamental must be wrong. I'm playing around with `dajax` and first everything seemed to be working right. That is the alert "Hello world" test went through. But for some reason I can't get the `assign` function working. I also tested the call in the shell, no problems there.

ajax.py

```
from dajax.core import Dajax
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register
def sayhello(request, pk):
    dajax = Dajax()

    dajax.alert(pk) #works
    dajax.assign('#ajaxize', 'innerHTML', 'invalid') #doesn't work
    return dajax.json()
```

HTML

```
<div id="ajax"><span id="ajaxize"></span></div>
```

I do have included the `{% load dajaxice_templatetags %}` and everything else [suggested on this blog](http://simonsstuffandthings.blogspot.nl/2012/05/installation-and-use-of-dajax-and.html).

**Edit**

I forgot to mention: my browser debugger says 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: clear_quotes'

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same problem and the only thing that I did was erase the line where "clear_quotes" was used. After that, the code worked.

You have to create a virtual enviroment to do that change.